# I am recieving a php warning regarding session_save_path()

Tags: php, session

I am using session_save_path() to save session data into a file.

The problem I am getting though is that I am getting this warning in my Test1.php file:

`Warning: Unknown: open(Session//sess_f3n6jeu79lsq91s9romabg1752, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (Session/) in Unknown on line 0`

What I have done is create an init.php and place the code below in this file:

```
<?php
 session_save_path('Session/'); 
 ?>
```

Then in the Test1.php file I included this code:

```
<?php

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
require_once 'init.php';                

session_start();

...

?>
```

In my directory it looks like this below:

```
Session (Folder)
init.php (file)
Test1.php (file)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it the session_save_path where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the warning:

> Unknown: open(Session//sess_f3

There is a '/' to much. The correct path is:

```
session_save_path('Session');
```

Make sure the **webserver process** has **access** to the folder.

Either the webserver process must be owner of the folder and permissions 700 or webserver process is not owner of the folder, permissions then 777!

Comment: Either the webserver process must be owner of the Folder and permissions 700 or webserver process is not owner of the Folder, permissions then 777!

Comment: Thank you, It was because of the slash which is strange and the permissions. I will definetly mark answer when I comeback. It is not lettin me at mo